# Adding margin to TableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am experimenting with Xcode 6 and Swift and having a little issue with the Interface Builder.

I created a new scene by dragging a TableViewController which comes with a TableView however when run it on a simulator the top cell is far too close to the top, it almost touches the central Date and Carrier logo.

As this seems to be a root view, I cannot add constraints, I also cannot find a way to adjust so that I have a margin that is flexible / responsive to different screen size.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to try to constrain the table to underneath the status bar, as this will cause the content of the scroll view to magically vanish as it goes above the 20pt mark.  Instead, allow it to continue to be full screen and simply set the table's contentInset property ([More info in documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentInset)).

This will cause the table to scroll as it normally would with the content going out the top of the screen, with the added ability to come to rest just under the status bar.

```
let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(statusBarHeight, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: Right I guess it needs to be done programmtically than rather than through Interface Builder?

Comment: @iQ. Unfortunately. In Interface Builder, you can adjust the insets of the scroll bar, but not the insets of the scrollview (table view) itself.